# Openlayers 2: [In Touch] Pinch zoom action triggers click event at the end. How to prevent click on pinch zoom

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, zoom

Openlayers 2: [In Touch] Pinch zoom action triggers click event at the end. How to prevent click event registered on map getting triggered when pinch is done